# Why wipe out web content?

Tags: caching, web-content

If caching web content is a good thing because it speeds up getting info from the internet why is cleaning out totally my cache a desirable thing to do?

Comment: Because sometimes the browser doesn't notice that the website has changed, and keeps using the cached version.

Comment: You generally only clear the cache when you think you're having a problem because of that.

Comment: What programming language do you use to wipe out the cache? :)

Comment: Your question is too broad - would you provide more details on the context. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for help on clarifying your question.

Answer (score 0):

A privacy reason is you do not want to others to know where you have been.
Now-a-days there is a privacy setting for this.
This also holds for "cookies", to stop those custom advertisements for something you long since bought.